# Given the variance of a zero mean random variable X, what is the largest and smallest possible value for E[exp(-jX)]

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a question that I am really eager to know the answer. It is as follows:

Given the variance of a zero mean random variable $\mathbf{X}$ is $\sigma^2$, what is the largest and smallest possible magnitude for $\mathbf{E}[e^{-j\mathbf{X}}]$? Here $j^2=-1$.

I checked from books that $\mathbf{E}[e^{-j\mathbf{X}}]$ correspond to the value of the characteristic function of the distribution of $\mathbf{X}$. So I wonder if there are any results that which distribution has the smallest or largest characteristic function.

And what are the corresponding distribution for $\mathbf{X}$ in each case?

When $\mathbf{X}$ is not zero mean but with mean $\mu$, does the same result hold?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is $j^2=-1$?...

Comment: You might see if: "The Moment-Generating Function and Negative Integer Moments" (Cressie, et al. 1981) is any help.

Comment: "And what are the corresponding distribution for them?" Are you referring to the distributions of $e^{-jX}$? The expectations are fixed values and have no distribution.

Comment: How do you define "the largest possible value" from a set included in the complex plane?

Comment: I have modified the question to address the problems you referred and make it clearer. Is there any answer to this?